# subquery equivalent for a join solution

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, subquery

We have two tables, User, Emails. They have relationship on `User.id == Emails.user_id`. If we are interested in those users who have more than one different emails, using `join` we can accomplish by this `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM User 
  JOIN Emails as EM1 ON User.id = Emails.user_id
  JOIN Emails as EM2 ON User.id = Emails.user_id
   Where EM1.address_line != EM2.address_line;
```

How can we achieve the same result using `subquery`?

Comment: Why do you want a subqeury?

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*
from users u
where (select count(*)
       from emails e
       where e.user_id = u.id
      ) >= 2;
```

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery that only returned `user_id` from `Emails` where the user has more than one email address.

Then join this to the `User` table on that `user_id`:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  User u
    INNER JOIN (
               SELECT  user_id
                 FROM  Emails
                 GROUP BY user_id
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
               ) a ON a.user_id = u.id
```

The subquery will only return `user_id` when there is *more than one row* in the `Emails` table for that user, which is what you asked for.

Note: SQL is untested.